# Best way to implement Azure App ID into C# application

Tags: c#, azure, onedrive

I'm developing an application that makes use of the [OneDrive SDK nugget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OneDriveSDK/) which uses Azure's App ID to authenticate API calls.

I'm not sure what's the best approach to implement that ID as I can't find any information about if it should be securely stored somehow or it can be implemented in a more flexible way (as plain text into a variable e.g).

Right now I'm storing that information in a separated file that has not been uploaded to github repository (as it's an open source project) but would like to know if that's not really necessary as it can be publicly avaible or there's a better way to handle it as I haven't used Azure Portal before.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application ID / client ID is not really a secret, though I suppose there isn't really any upside to sharing it either :)

If your app uses an application key / client secret, well, that has to be kept a secret.

The application ID is submitted to Azure AD in the sign-in request URL, so it is available to users who sign in to your app and can't really be kept a secret there.

Relevant portion of the [OAuth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-15):

> The authorization server issues the registered client a client
> identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
> information provided by the client.  **The client identifier is not a
> secret**; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used
> alone for client authentication.  The client identifier is unique to
> the authorization server.

Comment: I see... So as it's not a secret it makes no sense to keep it as it was, does it?
More than searching advantages in sharing it, was more a question about sharing project without "hidding" anything as I want it to be open source and I felt that was kind of strange for it to be that way while keeping secret something that doesn't seem to have the need to be secret (but wasn't totally sure as I hadn't arrived to that doc and had no previous experience).

Comment: Yeah, it isn't meant to be secret.